# Scrolling Flexbox Grid

Tags: html, css, flexbox, overflow

I'm trying to make a basic dashboarding layout with three columns and various different size boxes to hold graphs/tables/stats etc. I am trying to make the main dashboard a scrollable element, with navbars and other elements being stationary around it. My problem is that the scrolling doesn't allow me to scroll through all the different boxes, only 1 and a half of the rows. If anyone could assist me on this that would be awesome!

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.app {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dashboard {
  width: 1280px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  column-gap: 40px;
  row-gap: 20px;
  margin-left: 150px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.graph-box {
  width: 350px;
  height: 350px;
  border-radius: 20px 20px;
  background: #373737;
  color: white;
}

.graph {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 400px;
}

.table-box {
  width: 740px;
  height: 350px;
  border-radius: 20px 20px;
  background: #373737;
  color: white;
}

.table {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 125px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="app">
    <div class="dashboard">
      <div class="graph-box">
        <div class="graph">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="graph-box">
        <div class="graph">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="graph-box">
        <div class="graph">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="graph-box">
        <div class="graph">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="graph-box">
        <div class="graph">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="table-box">
        <div class="table">
          <table>
            <tr>
              <th>Col1</th>
              <th>Col2</th>
              <th>Col3</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Alpha</td>
              <td>Beta</td>
              <td>Gamma</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Delta</td>
              <td>Epsilon</td>
              <td>Zeta</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="graph-box">
        <div class="graph">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try setting the dashboard element height to `100vh` (or whatever size it needs to be), so the scroll actually knows how much real estate it has.

```css
.dashboard {
  width: 1280px;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  column-gap: 40px;
  row-gap: 20px;
  margin-left: 150px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.graph-box {
  width: 350px;
  height: 350px;
  border-radius: 20px 20px;
  background: #373737;
  color: white;
}

.graph {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 400px;
}

.table-box {
  width: 740px;
  height: 350px;
  border-radius: 20px 20px;
  background: #373737;
  color: white;
}

.table {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 125px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="app">
    <div class="dashboard">
      <div class="graph-box">
        <div class="graph">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="graph-box">
        <div class="graph">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="graph-box">
        <div class="graph">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="graph-box">
        <div class="graph">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="graph-box">
        <div class="graph">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="table-box">
        <div class="table">
          <table>
            <tr>
              <th>Col1</th>
              <th>Col2</th>
              <th>Col3</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Alpha</td>
              <td>Beta</td>
              <td>Gamma</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Delta</td>
              <td>Epsilon</td>
              <td>Zeta</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="graph-box">
        <div class="graph">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```